# Messages not appending properly

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Whenever I try to append a message to JSQMessages array it doesn't appear at the end of the collectionView

Error Demo: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/l0ExjQLlFmIH9MGQg

My code for retrieving messages:

```
func retrieveMessages() {

    let messagesRef = databaseRef.child("messages")
    var senderID : String!
    var recieverID : String!
    var message : JSQMessage!

   messagesRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

   if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

    self.messages.removeAll()

    for each in dictionary {

        let mediaType = each.value["mediaType"] as! String
        let text = each.value["text"] as! String
        let senderDisplayName = each.value["senderDisplayName"] as! String
         senderID = each.value["senderID"] as! String
         recieverID = each.value["reciverID"] as! String
        let time = each.value["time"] as! Int
        message = JSQMessage(senderId: senderID, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: text)

        if senderID == FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {

            if recieverID == self.userUID {

                self.messages.append(message)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }

          }

        }

    }
```

My code for sending messages:

```
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()
    finishSendingMessage(animated: true)

    let newMessage = messagesRef.childByAutoId()
    let currentTime = Date()
    let currentTimePassed = currentTime.timeIntervalSince1970
    let timeInt = Int(currentTimePassed)
    let messageData = ["text" : text, "senderID" : senderId, "senderDisplayName" : senderDisplayName, "mediaType" : "TEXT", "reciverID" : userUID, "time" : timeInt] as [String : Any]
    newMessage.setValue(messageData)
}
```

Comment: Can you show your codes in sending messages?

Comment: added my code for sending messages

Comment: What's the order of message data in your Firebase database? For example, the "good" text in your GIF demo, is it in the correct order in your database? If so, then we can safely assume that your ``receiving message`` code is wrong.